# update table in mysql by taking data from another table?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql.i have 2 tables NOTE_ONE and NOTE_TWO. each table has three columns as ID and NAME and MID. i need to update NOTE_TWO table's MID column with data from MID column of NOTE_ONE. but condition is NOTE_ONE and NOTE_TWO tables NAME should be equal. PLease suggest me how to write query for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick,

```
UPDATE NOTE_TWO n2, NOTE_ONE n1
SET n2.MID = n1.MID
WHERE n1.NAME = n2.NAME
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. i am getting sql syntax error after executing above query.error code:1064

Comment: @user1016403 try it again now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE note_two n2 set mid = (SELECT mid from note_one n1 where n1.name = n2.name)
```